# (Kotlin) Number guessing game doesn't register the correct userInput. Any tips?

Tags: android, kotlin

Super new to kotlin. My code seems to be bugging out at this line:

```
 else if (userInput == randomNumber){
        message = "Horray! You got it!\n Play again?"
    }
```

Seems like a quick fix but I'm not sure...When I input according to the hint, it doesn't register the correct answer at all. It's stuck on "higher/lower" and gives no option for the game to end. I'll attach the entire thing if it helps:
Thanks so much in advance.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlin.random.Random
import kotlin.random.Random.Default.nextInt


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var userAttempts = 0
    private val UPPER_BOUND = 100


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }

    fun buttonClick(view: View){
        val userInput = numberGuess.text.toString().toInt()
        userAttempts ++;


        val randomNumber = generateRandomNumber();

        var message = ""

        if (userInput < randomNumber) {
            message = "Higher!"
        }
        else if (userInput > randomNumber) {
            message = "Lower!"
        }
        else if (userInput == randomNumber){
            message = "Horray! You got it!\n Play again?"
        }

        hint.text = message
        attempts.text = "attempts: " + userAttempts

        numberGuess.text.clear()


    }
    private fun generateRandomNumber(): Int {
        return Random.nextInt(UPPER_BOUND)
    }
}
```

Comment: `When I input according to the hint, ` What do you mean by that? Are you using the hint each time to narrow down the number? If so you are generating a new number every time. To get the game to end you would have to guess it in one try. To fix this generate the number once per "game", until the user guesses the right one.

Comment: I am using the hint to narrow down the correct number, yes. But I didn't realize the code was generating a new number each time...how would i generate it just once per game?

Comment: declare `randomNumber` as a member of `MainActivity`, just like how you declare `userAttempts`. Then put `randomNumber = generateRandomNumber();` in `onCreate` instead of in `buttonClick`. You may also need a reset button for starting a new game or otherwise you need to kill the app to start a new game.

Comment: that makes sense. thank you! it works properly now. :)